# Error when trying to assign a variable a datetime from a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to assign a cell's datetime to a variable but keep getting an error. My code snip is below and am receiving the error at the `timein` variable. Note that in the first iteration, `counterTwo = 2` and `cellNextOne = 3`.

```
        ElseIf IsEmpty(Sheet3.Cells(counterTwo, 11)) = True And IsEmpty(Sheet3.Cells(cellNextOne, `enter code here`11)) = False And IsEmpty(Sheet3.Cells(counterTwo, 13)) = False Then
        Dim Timein As Date
        Dim Timeout As Date
        
        Sheet3.Cells(counterTwo, 29).Value = cellNextOne

        Timein = Sheet3.Cells(counterTwo, 15).Value
        Timeout = Sheet3.Cells(cellNextOne, 10).Value

        Sheet3.Cells(counterTwo, 26).Value = DateDiff("n", Timein, Timeout)
        Sheet3.Cells(counterTwo, 26).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
```

Note that I have also tried the below options:

```
Timein = TimeValue(Sheet3.Cells(counterTwo, 15).Value)

Timein = Sheet3.Cells(counterTwo, 15).Value2
```

but neither seem to work. Any ideas on the issue?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Try `Timein = cDate(Sheet3.Cells(counterTwo, 15).Value)`

Comment: If that does not work can you show what is in the cell that throws the error?

Comment: @ScottCraner Tried the CDate and that still didn't work. The cell is 2017.10.11 12:15:00. Also the error message says Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

Comment: That is because the cell contains a string that look like a date, one that Excel cannot parse natively.

Comment: use `Timein = cDate(Replace(Sheet3.Cells(counterTwo, 15).Value,".","-"))`

Comment: @ScottCraner This worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!